# input output file handling and rearranging data

Tags: tcl

I am new to Tcl I want to read data from a file lets say text.txt and content of the file is

```
Name     Delay  Trans  Load   
----------------------------
AND1_2X  1.50ns  0.1  1.25ff  
AND1_3X  1.75ns  0.2  1.98ff  
AND2_3X  2.37ns  0.3  2.27ff  
AND2_4X  1.82ns  0.5  2.54ff  
NAND1_2X 2.14ns  0.2  1.69ff  
NAND2_3X 2.48ns  0.3  2.11ff
```

now I want to read data and rearrange as with spaces

```
Name     Trans   Load  Delay  
-----------------------------
AND1_2X  0.1  1.25ff  1.50ns  
AND1_3X  0.2  1.98ff  1075ns  
AND2_3X  0.3  2.27ff  2.37ns  
AND2_4X  0.5  2.54ff  1.82ns  
NAND1_2X 0.2  1.69ff  2.14ns  
NAND2_3X 0.3  2.11ff  2.48ns
```

I have tried the code and I am getting the output as

```
Name Trans  Load Delay -----------------------------     AND1_2X 0.1  1.25ff 1.50ns AND1_3X 0.2  1.98ff 1.75ns AND2_3X 0.3  2.27ff 2.37ns AND2_4X 0.5  2.54ff 1.82ns NAND1_2X 0.2  1.69ff 2.14ns NAND2_3X 0.3  2.11ff 2.48ns
```

the code is

```
set fp [open "file1.txt" r+]  
set l1 {} 
while { [gets $fp data] >= 0 } {  
 set data1 [split $data "\n"]  
puts [lindex $data 0]  

 foreach line $data1 {  
 set cline [regsub " +" $line " "]  
 set dat1 [split $cline]  
 puts $dat1  
 puts [lindex $dat1 5]  
 lappend l1 [lindex $dat1  0]  
 lappend l1 [lindex $dat1  3]  
lappend l1 [lindex $dat1  4]  

 lappend l1 [lindex $dat1  5]  
 lappend l1 [lindex $dat1  1]  
}  
}  
puts $l1  
set x [join $l1]  
set fp1 [open "input.txt" w+]  
puts $fp1 $x  
close $fp1  
 close $fp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you've got is that you've got your final `join` wrong: you need to tell it to join with newlines instead of the default (single spaces):

```
set x [join $l1 "\n"]
```

Secondly, when you're producing a fixed-width line like:

```
AND1_2X  0.1  1.25ff  1.50ns
```

You should use the `format` command to do it. If you know C's `printf()` you should find it intuitive. Otherwise, use something like this:

```
# First, this is how to pick out the fields, assuming they're always present
set fieldData [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]

# Let's get some good names instead of using loads of lindex calls
lassign $fieldData name delay trans load

# Now let's transform that into the output line
lappend l1 [format "%-8s %3s  %5s  %6s" $name $trans $load $delay]
```

In particular, the `%3s` means “format this field” (from `$trans` in the code above) “in a right-aligned string field three characters wide”, and the `%-8s` means “format this field in a left-aligned string field eight characters wide”. This sort of thing is *great* for fixed width output.

If you're dealing with fixed width input with occasional missing fields, you need `scan` (which is sort of the inverse of `format`).

Finally, definitely special-case the header lines. That's hugely easier!